# Cumulative of last 12 months from latest communication date?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking  at counting the  number of  interactions  grouped by ID in the last 12 months for each unique  ID. The count starts from the  latest date to the last one  grouped by ID.

```
ID    date       
001   2022-02-01 
002   2018-03-26  
001   2021-08-05  
001   2019-05-01  
002   2019-02-01  
003   2018-07-01
```

Output is  something like the below.

```
ID    Last_12_Months_Count
001    2
002    2
003    1
```

How can I achieve this  in Pandas? Any function that would  count the months  based on the dates from the latest date per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['date'].gt(df.groupby('ID')['date'].transform('max')
                    .sub(pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)))
df1 = df[m]

df1 = df1.groupby('ID').size().reset_index(name='Last_12_Months_Count')
print (df1)
   ID  Last_12_Months_Count
0   1                     2
1   2                     2
2   3                     1
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID')['date']
         .agg(lambda x: x.gt(x.max() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)).sum())
         .reset_index(name='Last_12_Months_Count'))
print (df1)
   ID  Last_12_Months_Count
0   1                     2
1   2                     2
2   3                     1
```

For count multiple columns use named aggregation:

```
df['date1'] = df['date']

f = lambda x: x.gt(x.max() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)).sum()
df1 = (df.groupby('ID')
         .agg(Last_12_Months_Count_date = ('date', f),
              Last_12_Months_Count_date1 = ('date1', f))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   ID  Last_12_Months_Count_date  Last_12_Months_Count_date1
0   1                          2                           2
1   2                          2                           2
2   3                          1                           1
```

Comment: Thank you @jazrael for the innovative approach. Quickone what does this  part ```.agg(lambda x: x.gt(x.max() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)).sum())``` of the code do? In addition, is there a away in which I can count last 12 months of  date as above but based on the max of another date column in the same group? For example I have  "ID","date" and "date1". I count  the last 12 months in date one based on the max(date1) in the same groupby?

Comment: @Hummer Last date is max date, so solution compare maximal datetime minus one year and compare original column. So finally it count last year datetimes. If need compare by another column use first solution and change it to `m = df['date another col'].gt(df.groupby('ID')['date'].transform('max')`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Tried it  but is just giving  1 for  all counts regardless of the  number of 
 '''date another col''' within the  last year to '''date'''. Might it be related to transform(max)?

Comment: It worked @Jezrael. It was  my data  to some  extent. You are a legend.

Comment: Hello @Jezrael, with the  second  option, how can I be able  to add sums of  other  columns with numbers falling within the  12 months from ```date```?

Comment: @Hummer - not sure if understand, but in `agg` cannot set values by another column, because `agg` working with each column separately. In another words `agg` processing column `date` and then `date1`.